# Union Select from sorted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I would like to perform several SELECTs from a sorted table at the same time. My idea is the following:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table where parameter1 = 1 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table where parameter1 = 2 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
```

But it obviously doesn't work because of the ORDER BY. I've tried this too, but without success:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (SELECT * FROM unsorted_table where where parameter1 = 1 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC)
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (SELECT * FROM unsorted_table where where parameter1 = 2 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC)
```

If I used the following, as it is recommended on other threads here, I don't get what I need, since the table is sorted at the end:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table WHERE parameter1 = 1
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table WHERE parameter1 = 2
ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
```

Another limitation is, that I may not create new tables. So saving the sorted table in a new table and selecting from there is not an option either.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using WITH:

```
WITH xy AS (
SELECT TOP 5 * 
  FROM unsorted_table 
 WHERE parameter1 = 1 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
),
yz AS (
SELECT TOP 5 * 
  FROM unsorted_table 
 WHERE parameter1 = 2 ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
)
SELECT * FROM xy
UNION
SELECT * FROM yz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using subquery:

```
select * from 
(SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table WHERE parameter1 = 1
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM unsorted_table WHERE parameter1 = 2)a
ORDER BY parameter2 DESC, paramter3 DESC, parameter4 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select u.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by parameter1 order by parameter2 desc, paramter3 desc, parameter4) seq
      from unsorted_table 
      where parameter1 in (1,2)
     ) u
where seq <= 5;
```